# Encoding in VB.net dll doesn't work properly when the dll is called from C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, encoding

I have the following two functions in a VB.Net DLL. They emulate the CVL$ and MKL$ functions of old BASIC.

The function CVL takes a 4 byte string and converts it to an Int32 Integer. The MKL function does the opposite.

The functions are used internally in the DLL. When the DLL is called from a VB.NET project all works fine. When the DLL is called from C# the values are totally incorrect. Obviously the problem is with the encoding, but I've tried all of the options available (ASCII, UTF7, UTF8) but none work. Any ideas?

```
Function CVL(ByVal Value As String) As Integer
    Dim Encoding As System.Text.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default
    Dim Bytes() As Byte = Encoding.GetBytes(Value)
    Return BitConverter.ToInt32(Bytes, 0)
End Function
Function MKL(ByVal Value As Integer) As String
    Dim Encoding As System.Text.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default
    Dim Bytes() As Byte = BitConverter.GetBytes(Value)
    Return Encoding.GetString(Bytes)
End Function
```

Comment: I would argue that "definitely" is to strong term here. How was the dll compiled? How is it invoked? What "totally incorrect" values are you getting and and what inputs?

Comment: "When the DLL is called from C# the values are totally incorrect." what are you seeing in VB and what are you seeing in C#? Can you show a https://dotnetfiddle.net with a [mcve] of the problem?

Comment: Aside from what's already been mentioned, according to [Encoding.Default Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.default?view=net-6.0): _...using the default encoding is not recommended..._ You haven't mentioned whether your projects are using .NET Framework or .NET. Nonetheless, the referenced documentation contains information about both .NET Framework and .NET.

Comment: The VB.Net DLL is compiled with the .Net Framework 4 using VS 2022 as a class library. Mostly with default options. The DLL is a binary tree search engine which was created originally in VB4 about 25 years ago. It was converted to VB.Net about 20 years ago.

Comment: Which version of .NET does the C# side use?

Comment: The C# side is using .Net 5.0. What really intrigues me is that I would have thought that they were independent.

Comment: Another problem I found was that VB.Net permits CHR() with any value from 0 to 255, but if the VB.Net program is called from C# VB.Net raises an error if a value greater than 127 is used for CHR()

Comment: As for the totally incorrect values, let me explain. If you save a 4 byte integer to disk, you will have a string of 4 bytes, each one with a vaue of 0 to 255 depending on the value of the integer you have saved. When I call the function from a VB program the right number is produced. When I call the function from a C# program a different encoding is used and any of the four bytes greater than 127 are interpreted incorrectly and the wrong number is produced.

Comment: .NET 5 is no longer supported. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/microsoft-net-and-net-core) for more information. You may consider moving your project to .NET 6.

Comment: According to [What's new in .NET 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-5#net-5-doesnt-replace-net-standard): _if you plan to share code between .NET Framework, .NET Core, and .NET 5 workloads, you can do so by specifying netstandard2.0...For more information see [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?tabs=net-standard-1-0#select-net-standard-version)_

Answer (score 0):

`string` isn't a byte buffer, it has very hard rules for encoding. I can easily see how the normal encoding rules will lengthen or shorten the resulting bytes that you're then using to convert to an integer. In fact, even if everything works perfectly, your string has twice as many bytes as the resulting integer. Have you given half a thought about what happens to the other 4 bytes you're silently dropping?

Either do the right thing and use byte buffers (or even better spans), or do your own manual decoding from strings to integers and the other way around. Writing something equally broken, but at least well defined, is pretty trivial:

```
static int CVL(string s) =>
    s[3] << 24 | s[2] << 16 | s[1] << 8 | s[0];
```

Comment: It is true that string isn’t a byte buffer, but the original program was designed that way and it works. It puts different values in a string (bytes, int16s, int32s, singles, doubles, and strings) and saves them to disk, and then recovers them from disk as a string and reconverts. It can do a search through millions of values and return a result in less than a millisecond. 
Now we would like to be able to call the DLL from a C# program but ran into the problem that apparently C# changes the way the VB.Net program does encoding.

Comment: Perhaps a better question would be: Is there a way to isolate the VB.Net DLL so that C# doesn’t affect the way it works?

Comment: C# has nothing to do with it, both C# and VB.NET compile to the same IL. Your code is just fundamentally broken.

Comment: Perhaps it is broken, but it has worked for twenty years and continues to work as long as it is called from VB and not C#. By the way this code is found in software used by thousands of accountants in Spain and accountants don't like errors.

Comment: I found another, simpler example.
Dim A as string = Chr(128)
Put that in a VB.Net DLL. If you call it from VB no problem. If you call it from C# it provokes a fatal error. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Solution to problem.

1. Upgrade project to .NET 6 (https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/upgrade-assistant/tutorial/install-upgrade-assistant)
2. Add the `System.Text.Encoding.CodePages` NuGet package to solution
3. Register encoding in Startup.
4. Create a global variable (Encod in the sample) and assign to encoding in startup

   ```
   Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance)
   Encod = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)
   ```
5. Modify the functions to use encoding.

   ```
   Function CVL(ByVal Value As String) As Integer
       Dim Encoding As System.Text.Encoding = Encod
       Dim Bytes() As Byte = Encoding.GetBytes(Value)
       Return BitConverter.ToInt32(Bytes, 0)
   End Function
   Function MKL(ByVal Value As Integer) As String
       Dim Encoding As System.Text.Encoding = Encod
       Dim Bytes() As Byte = BitConverter.GetBytes(Value)
       Return Encoding.GetString(Bytes)
   End Function
   ```

I still don't understand why the C# program would affect the VB.Net program internally but this code solves the problem.

Thanks to those who gave me a couple of good ideas.